# Animating border colour change from bottom up?

Tags: css

So I have been searching to find a way to change the color of the bottom border of my navigation bar links with a linear animation starting from the bottom going upwards. I was able to find a thread with some code that I semi-understand, just a few CSS lines which has sent me in the right direction, however the colour change is animated from the top down, whereas I would like the opposite.

I am using Bootstrap if that makes any different, is there any way I can do the opposite and have the transition start from the bottom and go upwards? My code is posted below...

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {}

#header-nav {
 background-color: #262626;
 font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-bottom: #212121 thick solid;
}

#header-nav .container {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
/* border-bottom: purple thick solid;*/
 margin: 0px;
}
/*212121*/
#header-nav a {
 color: #FFF;
 margin-right: 2rem;
 padding: 10px;
/* border-bottom: purple thick solid; */
 transition-property: all;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

#header-nav a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
/* background-color: purple;*/
 border-bottom: white thick solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

  <!-- Meta & Other -->
  <title>Infamous | Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
  <meta name="keywords" content ="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming">
  <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/default.css">
  
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
 

 </head>



 <body>

  <header>
   <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <div class="container">
     <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
     <a href="#about"><i class="fas fa-question"></i> About</a>
     <a href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
     <a href="#vote"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i> Vote</a>
     <a href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- JavsScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gradient for this:

```css
.box {
  background:#000;
  padding:10px 20px;
}

a {
  display:inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding-bottom:10px; /* control the space for the gradient */
  background:
   linear-gradient(currentColor,currentColor) 
   bottom /* make it bottom */
   /100% 0px  /*start at heght = 0; */
   no-repeat;
  transition:0.3s all;
}
a:hover {
  background-size:100% 6px; /* make the height 6px*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href=""> a link </a>
</div>
```

Another syntax where you adjust the position instead:

```css
.box {
  background:#000;
  padding:10px 20px;
}

a {
  display:inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding-bottom:10px; 
  background:
   linear-gradient(currentColor,currentColor) 
   left 0 bottom -7px 
   /100% 6px 
   no-repeat;
  transition:0.3s all;
}
a:hover {
  background-position:left 0 bottom 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href=""> a link </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Uhmm something doesn't quite seem right lol [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/MrWardy/pen/MWKarBE)

Comment: Adding transition: 0.3s all it now works, sort of, but adding `display: inline-block` makes the navbar far too thick, and also for some reason the bar when you hover isn't actually where the border is? How can I make that the case where it would overlap the purple border?

Comment: Never mind, to fix the thickness I removed the padding from `#header-nav .container` and I have opted to not have a pre-excisting border on the bottom before hovering, I like both ways equally as good and since this is simpler I will go with it. Thank you for the help.